# setting values in numpy matrix with array of indices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, indexing

Consider a mxn matrix A. I computed the indices of the maximum of each row, yielding an array of dimension m.

How can I use this array of indices to set the values in a second matrix B of the same shape as A in each row to 0.

Example:

```
     A = [[1,2] ,[3,4]] 

     np.argmax(A,1) --> [1,1]

     B = [[1,1] ,[1,1]]
```

I want to have:

```
  B = [[1 0] ,[1 0]]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
B[np.arange(B.shape[0]),np.argmax(A,1)] = 0
```

Comment: If I use B= np.ones((20, 4), dtype='bool'), then this does not work? A is also of shape 20x4

Comment: @Sarah try the edit