# Fill non rectangular slice of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Is it possible to do any operation for example fill in a non-rectangular slice of the NumPy array with NumPy itself?

For example imaging, we have a NumPy array in which the first index in each row represents the limit. and we want to fill out of limit items with the latest element inside the limit.

```py
mat = np.array([
    [0, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    [1, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    [3, 4, 5, 6, 6],
    [2, 4, 5, 5, 5],
])

index = mat[:, 0] # array([0, 1, 3, 2])
```

Is it possible to fill each row from `index+1` to its end with the corresponding `index+1` in its row?

```py
mat[0, 1:] = mat[0, 1] # 4
mat[1, 2:] = mat[1, 2] # 4
mat[2, 4:] = mat[2, 4] # 6
mat[3, 3:] = mat[3, 3] # 5
```

```sh
mat[: index+1:] = mat[: index+1]
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

**NOTE**: I know it seems too specific, but I can not explain what is in mind easier without the example.

Comment: I don't think it is specific. To make it specific, please give an input, and the desired output/

Comment: There isn't a "slice" that can do this.  So iterating on the rows is a good option; if not the fastest it's the easiest to understand and implement.  Using ideas developed for padding arrays of variable length  it is possible to create a boolean mask of the slots you want to fill. And then `mat[mask] = [4,4,..., 6,... 5,...]`

Comment: Another current questions shows how to set one element per row, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70732955/setting-values-in-numpy-matrix-with-array-of-indices; but this doesn't work for slices.  As you found slices can only be defined with a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [134]: mat = np.array([
     ...:     [0, 4, 4, 4, 4],
     ...:     [1, 4, 4, 4, 4],
     ...:     [3, 4, 5, 6, 6],
     ...:     [2, 4, 5, 5, 5],
     ...: ])
     ...: 
In [135]: index = mat[:, 0]+1          # add the 1 here
In [136]: for i,v in enumerate(index):
     ...:     mat[i,v:] = mat[i,v]
     ...: 
     ...: 
In [137]: mat
Out[137]: 
array([[0, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [1, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 6],
       [2, 4, 5, 5, 5]])
```

construct a boolean mask (as suggested for padding problems)

```
In [141]: np.arange(5)>=index[:,None]
Out[141]: 
array([[False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True]])
```

This is `True` where we want to fill in values.  But the next trick is to create an array of values like this:

```
In [142]: mat[_]
Out[142]: array([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 5, 5])
```

We get the number of fills per row with a sum:

```
In [143]: mask = np.arange(5)>=index[:,None]
In [144]: mask.sum(axis=1)
Out[144]: array([4, 3, 1, 2])
```

And get the fill array by using those to repeat the selected row value:

```
In [148]: mat[np.arange(4),index].repeat(mask.sum(axis=1))
Out[148]: array([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 5, 5])
In [149]: mat[mask] = _
```

Decide for yourself whether that "vectorized" approach is worth your time.